# How to use the "build a community around your business" new Facebook feature?

Tags: facebook

Facebook added a new feature that encourages you to create a Facebook group associated with the Facebook page of your business. Supposedly this would be better for your business. So far, after you associate a page with a group, I've seen these features.

- The Facebook page becomes admin of the group
- The Facebook page is linked in the top part of the group
- The Facebook page is linked at the right of the group
- The group is linked in the Facebook page
- They encourage you to create a post in your Facebook page for promoting the associated Facebook group.

But I haven't seen any change in activity neither in the Facebook page nor the Facebook group. Is there anything more you can do with these features? or are there more features related to this I havent seen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't realize that Facebook had made this change--must go explore! I was on the verge of abandoning a page for a group, myself.

The important point is that Pages are useless for building community. Groups aren't a great community tool, but they are as good as it gets on Facebook--people can post easily to it, share "stuff," etc.

I'd experiment. That's what the web is for. (I'm going to do the same and may come update if I get results quickly.)

If you aren't seeing a change in activity, that may mean that people don't understand that things have changed, or it may indicate a lack of engagement. Experiment. Make sure you communicate periodically that the Group is there. Think of ways that might engage your community (discussion topics, perhaps? Polls/Contents? Links?) and keep trying them.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook made recently an addition to this feature that is really useful to make the group grow. So now you have a Facebook page, and a Facebook group associated with it, that's seen as one of the first entries of the Facebook Page. Well, inside the Facebook page now they give you an option to invite the people from the Facebook Page, to the Facebook group. I'm using that recently added tool and the group really grows.